# Python installation messed up

Tags: python, anaconda

I've installed csvn a few weeks ago and apparently this installed its own version of python (2.5) and now I cant seem to change back to any other Python Version.
When I try to start Anaconda in cmd, it just shows me the following error:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\csvn\Python25\'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\csvn\\Python25\\'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\csvn\\Python25\\'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\csvn\\Python25\\'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\csvn\\Python25\\'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\python39.zip',
    'C:\\csvn\\Python25\\\\DLLs',
    'C:\\csvn\\Python25\\\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00003f30 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

This program messed up almost all of my environmental variables and I dont know how to set them back to default :/

Comment: Type WinKey env return, select Yes to change system settings, in the GUI select the bottom right corner Environment Variables... and remove Python 25 from the path environment variables for user and system.

Comment: @PeterWood Python 25 is actually not there in the environment Path variables :/